# Text disappears but the container is still there when resizing page

Tags: html, css, web, error-handling, frontend

Every time I’m resizing my screen size, text disappears. I checked live element selection and still see the div container where it should be. It’s only the text which is disappearing. I have tried everything but to no avail. When I try moving it to left or right or resize it, it works. But it’s just the text which is not visible. Please help me out.

Update: I checked and the problem is with anchor tag. I am still not able to fix it.

Comment: always provide your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please see [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).